# Why is my Laravel Lumen listener being called twice?

Tags: php, laravel, events, listener, lumen

My listener is being called twice, but the event is fired only once.

I got the code from Lumen 5.7 example and have no idea where is my mistake.

**bootstrap/app.php**

```
$app->register(App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class);
```

**app/Providers/EventServiceProvider.php**

```
protected $listen = [
    'App\Events\NewAuthEvent' => [
        'App\Listeners\SendNewAuthListener',
    ],
];
```

**app/Events/NewAuthEvent.php**

```
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use App\Data\Entity\User;
use App\Data\Entity\Authorization;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class NewAuthEvent
{
    use SerializesModels;

    public $user;

    public $auth;

    public function __construct(User $user, Authorization $auth)
    {
        Log::debug("once :)");
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->auth = $auth;
    }
}
```

**app/Listeners/SendNewAuthListener.php**

```
use App\Events\NewAuthEvent;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use App\Data\Service\MessengerService;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class SendNewAuthListener
{
    private $messenger;

    public function __construct(MessengerService $messenger)
    {
        Log::debug("twice :(");
        $this->messenger = $messenger;
    }

    public function handle(NewAuthEvent $event)
    {
        Log::debug("twice as well :(");
        $this->messenger->new($event->user, $event->auth);
    }
}
```

**firing the event:**

```
event(new NewAuthEvent($objUser, $objAuthorization));
```

What am I missing? Is there some other parameter or config to be seted?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the handle method being called twice or just the constructor?

Comment: @Devon The handle method is being called twice as well.

Comment: Strange, the only way you'll get to the bottom of it is by using a debugger or logging the backtrace.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. Check your `EventsServiceProvider`. If your are using a `shouldDiscoverEvents` method that returns true, removing it may solve your issue. See comment by **andnacho** [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/events-are-handled-twice).